# What is the energy consumption of the brain?

Tags: neuroscience, metabolism

What is the energy consumption of the brain, and is there a difference in consumption when waking and sleeping?

Comment: Do you mean the activity as visible in an EEG? Because the brain mainly uses up energy as far as I know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you mean energy consumption.

Talking in round numbers the daily energy requirement of a sedentary human is 2,500 kcal. It's usually said that the brain uses 20% of this energy.

What does this mean in terms of power consumption?

```
500 kcal = 500 x 1000 x 4.2 J  -[1]
24 h = 24 x 60 x 60 s          -[2]   

1 W = 1 J/s

therefore brain power  = [1]/[2] = approximately 24 W
```

Most of the energy consumed by the brain is used in maintaining membrane potentials so energy is used continuously. I would think that there will be very little difference between waking and sleeping.

Comment: One ref for the breakdown of energy costs: Laughlin, S. (2001). Energy as a constraint on the coding and processing of sensory information. Current Opinion in Neurobiology, 11(4):475-480.

Comment: The cortical activity pattern is measurably different between rest and sleep states. I think there would be measurable differences.

Comment: Adding to this: There is a difference of active vs. inactive brain regions in terms of energy consumption. This is used in [PET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positron_emission_tomography) (positron emission tomography) scans. Here you enrich radioactive glucose in the regions which are more active (=need more energy) and make them visible.

Comment: I'm not denying that brain activity will require more energy (to restore membrane potential), I'm just dubious that it will be a very big difference (the brain is active during sleep too). I await an answer that provides evidence about this.